# How to filter/sort properly with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've just created some very simple database (index) of "movies" using this tutorial : http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/

Now, I try to copy/paste the instruction to create a multifield mapping for the "director" field :

```
    curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/_mapping" -d'
{
   "movie": {
      "properties": {
         "director": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
                "director": {"type": "string"},
                "original": {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

But after this, if I post this query, I get no result :

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "term": { "director.original": "Francis Ford Coppola" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

result :

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

And if I try to sort using this :

```
http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/_search?sort=title.original:asc
```

I get the whole table (type) in random order (same order as with no "sort" instruction) :

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":6,"max_score":null,"hits":[{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"4","_score":null,"_source":
{
    "title": "Apocalypse Now",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1979,
    "genres": ["Drama", "War"]
},"sort":[null]},{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"5","_score":null,"_source":
{
    "title": "Kill Bill: Vol. 1",
    "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
    "year": 2003,
    "genres": ["Action", "Crime", "Thriller"]
},"sort":[null]},{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"1","_score":null,"_source":
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1972,
    "genres": ["Crime", "Drama"]
},"sort":[null]},{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"6","_score":null,"_source":
{
    "title": "The Assassination of Jesse James by the Coward Robert Ford",
    "director": "Andrew Dominik",
    "year": 2007,
    "genres": ["Biography", "Crime", "Drama"]
},"sort":[null]},{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"2","_score":null,"_source":
{
    "title": "Lawrence of Arabia",
    "director": "David Lean",
    "year": 1962,
    "genres": ["Adventure", "Biography", "Drama"]
},"sort":[null]},{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"3","_score":null,"_source":
{
    "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
    "director": "Robert Mulligan",
    "year": 1962,
    "genres": ["Crime", "Drama", "Mystery"]
},"sort":[null]}]}}
```

So would you tell me what am I missing in this basic use of ElasticSearch ? why no filtering or sorting on my custom "director" field ?

Comment: Note how your `sort` field is `[null]`: that's because `title.original` does not exist

Comment: No, when you use a field which does not exist, u get an exception.

Comment: Ok, did you create mapping _first_ and _then_ added data? Or reverse?

Comment: data first, then update mapping to set director as multi-field, just like the tutorial.

Comment: So now try in reverse order. ES will not reanalyze all your data on mapping change (imagine you have some TB of documents and add new filed to the mapping - reindexing all will take forever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating the multi-field properly. You should do it like this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/_mapping" -d '{
   "movie": {
      "properties": {
         "director": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "original": {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Also note that in that tutorial they are using a deprecated way of declaring multi-fields, i.e. with `"type": "multi_field"`. Now we do it the way I've shown above.

EDIT form comment below : After changing the mapping to multi-field, you need to re-run the 6 indexing queries to re-index the six movies so the director.original field gets populated.

Comment: I've corrected my question with the right "multi_field" instruction. I've also tried your non deprecated way to create the multi-field, but I have exactly the same results.

Comment: You need to wipe your index and re-index the data.

Comment: Yes, it's already done using "curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/movies/" then recreating the whole index (just a simple copy/paste of the tutorial, hope u can try this on your own ES).

Comment: Not sure why you changed my `PUT` to a `POST`, as `PUT` was correct since we only wanted to "upgrade" one field in an existing mapping. Besides, `PUT` is also what they used in that article ;)

Comment: I guess both PUT and POST are technically and semantically correct for this, but it's not really what is important for me as u can guess :)   can u tell me why full re-creation doesnt work as expected ?

Comment: I know it was just a side comment ;-) I followed the article and it worked out for me. After modifying the mapping to upgrade the `director` field to a multi-field, I re-ran the indexing queries for the six movies and the search for `director.original` worked and returned me the two expected movies by Coppola. Note that if you wiped the `movies` index, you need to create the `director` multi-field **before** re-indexing your data. That might be the culprit.

Comment: well, I'm pretty sure u've done something u always do and which is not explicitly in the tutorial : what are u calling "re-indexing", I thought applying the multifield index to "director" was already creating a new index for this field.

Comment: I've not done anything else special that isn't in the tutorial. After changing the mapping to multi-field, you simply need to re-run the 6 indexing queries to re-index the six movies so the `director.original` field gets populated. That's all.

Comment: Ok, I guess I missed this discrete instruction : "With our new shiny mapping in place we can re-index one or both of the movies directed by Francis Ford Coppola (copy from the list of initial indexing requests above) and try the search request that filtered by author again." That's rly not natural for a novice cause it's not what u would do with a new mapping in Hibernate or a new index in a classic DBMS. Thanks for your answer, I'll try it today.

Comment: The way it works in ES is that you're supposed to cleverly craft your mappings beforehand to support your use cases and then you can index your data as you wish. The bottom line is that every time you change a mapping, you need to re-index your data, that's how it works in ES. That's why it's better to spend a bit more time at design time to craft your mappings so that you don't have to worry about that later on.